# Writing SEO friendly url gets infinite loop asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, url-rewriting

I am trying to write SEO friendly URL for my website. for this I have written following code in my global.asax.

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        HttpContext incoming = HttpContext.Current;
        string oldpath = incoming.Request.Path;
        string imgId = string.Empty;
        //   string imgName = string.Empty;
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"N/(.+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(oldpath);

        if (matches.Count > 0)
        {

            imgId = matches[0].Groups[1].ToString();
            // imgName = matches[0].Groups[2].ToString();
            string newPath = String.Concat("~/inner.aspx?Id=", imgId);
            incoming.RewritePath(String.Concat("~/inner.aspx?Id=", imgId), false);
        }

    }
```

But When the regular expression matches, this code goes on infinite loop. When I apply debugger in this code, It moves infinitely when the regular expression Matches. Please help me regarding this problem.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the regex, it matches an `n` or `N`, then a `/`, and then 0 or more characters other than a newline. What is the input? Why use `IgnorePatternWhitespace` if you do not use spaces in your pattern? What line does the freeze occur on?

Comment: On applying debugger what I am getting is when URL qualifies the regex, the  event Application_BeginRequest  is fired again and again. I don't think this problem has anything to do with regex.

Comment: For an example when user writes URL like www.upnews360.in/N/xyz it is rewritten as www.upnews360.in/inner.aspx?Id=xyz.

Comment: You code correctly gets to the `string newPath` line, and the `newPath` is `~/inner.aspx?Id=N/xyz`. You need a regex fix. I think I have a solution.

Comment: yes my code is correctly getting newpath i.e. ~/inner.aspx?Id=N/xyz. But On applying debugger in this code, I see very unexpected behaviour. It moves on continuously. I also changed the Regex as suggested by you but no help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems problem related to Regex.

It can be due to excessive backtracking. See more about backtracking [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg578045.aspx#Backtracking)

If you are using ASP.Net version 4.5 then try to use .NET 4.5's new Regex timeout feature [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160210(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware that your regex is set to ignore case, thus `n` is caught before the first `/`.

You need either to get the last `n` and everything that is not `/`:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"N/([^/]+)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Or, use a case sensitive search:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"N/(.+)");
```

Comment: No help.  I see very unexpected behaviour of debugger arrow It moves continuously

Comment: At least now the regex is working and we know it is no longer an issue.

Comment: exactly.And thanx for that:-)